# Physics Simulations in Java

Tags: java, physics

Are there any good books that teach how to make simple physics simulations in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I recommend you this one: [http://www.amazon.com/Physics-Game-Programmers-Grant-Palmer/dp/159059472X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159059472X)

Also you can check a lot of physics for games developed in Java:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Developing-Games-Java-David-Brackeen/dp/1592730051](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592730051)
- http://javapdfbooks.blogspot.com/2009/07/physics-for-game-programmers.html ('free')
- Physics for Game Developers (is in C++)

I hope that this helps you!